# Inverse Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, fibonacci-numbers

I was having fun with Fibonacci numbers, and I had the idea to consider the sequence
$
F_n=F_{n-1}^{-1}+F_{n-2}^{-1}
$
instead.

I wrote a simple program to compute the first terms and the sequence seemed chaotic, although converging to $\sqrt{2}$ whatever $F_0$ and $F_1$ were. ($F_0,F_1\neq0$).

How can I prove that the sequence indeed converges, and it converges to $\sqrt{2}$? Is it hopeless to try and find a closed-term formula for $F_n$?

Comment: There is a bit of information at https://oeis.org/A057677 and https://oeis.org/A066932

Comment: @rogerl I see. This should be enough to prove the convergence alone too. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F_n$ converge to $x$. Therefore, $$x=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2}{x} $$so $$x^2=2$$providing solutions of $$x=\pm\sqrt2$$
If you try starting with negative numbers you should converge to $-\sqrt2$.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about finding the closed-term formula? Since it is probably chaotic I don't think it's possible...

Comment: This proves the possible limit value, but note that you still need to show convergence separately

Comment: If $F_0$ and $F_1$ are both positive, the whole sequence is positive. If $F_{n-2},F_{n-1}<\sqrt2$ then $F_n>\sqrt2$ and if $F_{n-2},F_{n-1}>\sqrt2$ then $F_n<\sqrt2$. $F_{n-1}$ and $F_n$ are on opposite sides of $\sqrt2$ so $F_{n+1}>\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{2}$ and is closer to $\sqrt2$. Doing this repeatedly leads to the sequence converging to $\sqrt2$. This should be similar when $F_0$ and $F_1$ are both negative and converges to $-\sqrt2$. If $F_0$ and $F_1$ are on opposite sides of 0, I'm guessing you get to a point where $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}$ are on the same side of 0, leading to a convergence.

Comment: @SaiMehta The terms might keep getting closer to $\sqrt{2}$, but how do you know that get arbitrarily close to it?

Comment: This is a good intuition, but not a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Milten yes, this doesn't prove that it converges. However $|F_n-\sqrt{2}|<2\cdot2^{-n/2}$. See rogerl's comment above, below the question.

Answer (score -2):

$$Fn = \frac {(\frac {1＋\sqrt {5}}{2})^n－(\frac {1-\sqrt {5}}{2})^n}{\sqrt {5}}$$

Comment: This is Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers. How does this solve the problem?